# How to get the index of updated point in graph using Highcharts and how to reload the data till that index

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

Hello I am getting my data from csv file and I am using 'this.update(0)' on my chart to update any point through a mouse click therefore making that point equal to 0 on y axis but what I want is that when I click on a point it first gets me the index of that point and then reload the data again from same csv file but this time the data values should not go beyond the index. e.g if I clicked on a point at x=10 then I should be able to reload the data again from file till x=9 and store the newly loaded data to an array.

Here is a part my code where data has to be reloaded. It reloads the entire data which is not need, that's probably I am not getting the right index or if there is someother problem kindly help. Thank you.

```
plotOptions: {
series: {
cursor: 'pointer',
point: {
events: {
click: function() {
var x= this.update(0);
$.get('testFile.csv', function(data) {
var lines = data.split('\n');
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
var items = line.split(',');
var series = {
data: []
};
$.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
if(itemNo<x){
series.data.push(parseFloat(item)); }   });
options.series.push(series);
});
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get index use: `this.series.processedXData.indexOf(this.x)`

Now, remove creating new chart, but instead update each of points with values, something like this:

```
var actSeries = this.series; //needed for scope range

...
... 
...

$.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
    if(itemNo<x){
        actSeries.data[itemNo].update(parseFloat(item), false);
    });
});
actSeries.chart.redraw();
```

Comment: I don't understand where would this command will store my index 'this.series.processedXData.indexOf(this.x)' because in my if condition below x is the variable which I was trying to get using this.x so in your case should it be var  x=this.series.processedXData.indexOf(this.x);.....P.s I want to get index and update value simultaneously.How do I do that?

Comment: It doesn't fulfill the requirement because my new/reloaded graph consists of a points which were on left side of the updated point. I don't want those points to be displayed which were on right hand side of updated point.